# Bookmark seems to not save input or output values for my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am currently trying to make a shiny app that can do some basic project planning based on some dropdowns and time objects.

One thing I would really like to be able to do with this app is to be able to have its state saved, so that people can use the app continuously, rather than restarting the app each and every time.

The problem I am having is that the bookmarking tool does not seem to save input values used in the app. It does create a link, but the link just sends me back to if I just opened the app from the R script rather from a bookmarked link.

There are a few things I am thinking might be the issue:

1. It may be a version issue: Currently I have access to R 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness". Due to a strict IT department, it is not easily feasible to update my version. If it is a version issue, that is fine, but I am not quite ready to write that off as a version issue without exhausting my options, as asking for an upgraded version is not easy.
2. I tried using onBookmark and onBookmark, but none of those options seem to be working. I have seen some threads seem to indicate that reactiveValues need to be used, but I dont know if I can use my table outputs for that.
   http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/advanced-bookmarking.html
3. I have checked simpler codes, such as the exampled in the bookmark main page and they seem to work.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html

```
rm(list = ls())  
graphics.off() 

################################## OMM Dashboard for Reporting #####################################
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "App V 1.0",
                          titleWidth = 300)



sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(

    menuItem(text = 'Welcome', tabName = 'welcome', icon = icon('globe')),
    menuItem(text = "Foobar", tabName = 'FB', icon = icon("line-chart"))
  ),
  width = 300
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(
    bookmarkButton(),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'welcome',
              box(h1("Lorem Ipsum"),
                  h3("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vix decore partem menandri ad, ius eu harum labitur suavitate. An veritus facilisi quaerendum eam, at vis dicat praesent. Modo agam ex pri, te cum legimus persecuti voluptatibus, nec ignota deserunt et. Simul verear regione eu nec, mel insolens oportere intellegebat eu, eius regione adversarium vis id. Posse senserit gubergren pro ei. Expetendis deterruisset ea est, per porro inimicus id, et platonem volutpat qui."))),


      tabItem(tabName = 'FB',
              titlePanel("Foo Bar"),



              sidebarLayout(


                sidebarPanel(


                  selectInput(inputId  = 'Foo',
                              label = "Foo",
                              choices = c("Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3")),

                  dateRangeInput(inputId = 'foo_date',
                                 label = "Foo date",
                                 min = '2001-01-01',
                                 max = '2100-01-01',
                                 format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),

                  selectInput(inputId = "Bar",
                              label = "Bar",
                              choices =c("Level 1", "Level 2", "Level 3")),

                  dateRangeInput(inputId = 'bar_date',
                                 label = "Bar Date",
                                 min = '2017-01-01',
                                 max = '2100-01-01',
                                 format = "yyyy-mm-dd")

                ),
                mainPanel(
                  dataTableOutput(outputId = 'tableFB')
                ))

      )







    )))


ui <- function(request){
  dashboardPage(skin = "blue", header = header, 
                sidebar = sidebar, 
                body = body)
}


server <- function(input, output){








  dat_FB <- shiny::reactive(data.frame(
    Topic = c("Foo",
              "Bar"),
    Start_date = c(format(input$Foo_date[1]),
                   format(input$Bar_date[1])),
    End_date =c(format(input$Foo_date[2]),
                format(input$Bar_date[2])),
    Scope = c(input$Foo,
              input$Bar)))

  output$tableFB <- renderDataTable({
    dat_FB()
  })



}

options(browser = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe") 

enableBookmarking(store = "server")
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

I would like to have it to where when I click the bookmark button, and it provide the the inputs used before the bookmark was applied, rather than the default inputs.

Let me know if I can clarify anything further,
Thank you.